# Plugin or setting in Ubuntu 23.10 for browsing apps as in 22.04

Tags: 22.04, 23.10

I need help with sth, I am coming to Ubuntu 23.10 after thinking about it a lot as a want some of the features from 23.04 and 23.10 releases.

I am **upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS**, and I've tried Ubuntu 23.10 on a virtual machine before deciding to upgrade. I have noticed that in the apps navigation there is a change, apps are navigated with some arrows instead of how it is done in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (see screenshots).

As you can see in the screenshots, in Ubuntu **22.04** I can **navigate the apps by moving the cursor to the side of the screen and click**, while in **23.10 I have to click the arrow**. This is very annoying for me as it takes more time to hit a little arrow instead of just the border of the screen, and it makes the experience slower unsatisfactory.

So my question is: Is there some extension or setting so that I can still browse the apps as I currently do in Ubuntu 22.04?

Thanks in advance

[23.10 Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTK5l.png)

[22.04 LTS Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K4VG.png)

Comment: Gnome is well-known for tinkering, making changes big and small with each release, and you are jumping three releases. Gnome users generally accept that change is constant.

Comment: Browse https://extensions.gnome.org/ to see if such an extension exists. If you discover one that meets your needs, come back and answer your own question!